# How to make SlideUp stop at acertain height

Tags: jquery, slideup

I'm using a slideUp and slideDown plugin. I was wondering how i can make it so the div only slide ups to a certain height.

Second question 
How can I make my the same button the target for the div to slide up and down?

Here's what I m currently trying to use

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
     $("#Menu").slideDown( 'slow', function(){ 
         $(".log").text('Slide Down Transition Complete');
      });
  });

  $("#toggle").click(function(){
     $("#Menu").slideUp('slow', function(){ 
         $(".log").text('Slide Up Transition Complete');
      });
  });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could create a custom animation for slideUp. Let's say you want to slideUp to a height of 20px:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("#Menu").animate({height: 20}, 'slow', function(){ 
        $(".log").text('Slide Up Transition Complete');
    });
});
```

Comment: everybody forgets the pixels in their animate properties! You need `{height: '20px'}`; also, great answer ;)

Comment: It always works without 'px'. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/timing/mydRQ/1/

Comment: thank you and...although it seems close to what I need it's still not performing correct. Here is the URL file:///Users/gregtaylor/Desktop/CAITMIZZI.COM/test.html

Comment: @timing - it works without the pixels because your browser is kind; you are defining a css property, remember, and they always require valid units.

Comment: @Kato: jQuery appends the 'px' itself, see line 8440 (and some others) in jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#toggle").click(function(){
      var down = $('#Menu').css('height') == '100px';
      if( down ) {
         $('#Menu').animate( {height: '500px'}, 'slow', function(e) {
            $(".log").text('Slide Down Transition Complete');
         });
      }
      else {
         $('#Menu').animate( {height: '100px'}, 'slow', function(e) {
            $(".log").text('Slide Up Transition Complete');
         });      
      }
   });
```

Comment: thanks again...this seems even closer. For some reason it's still messing up. the animation doesn't come to a full stop...it just sort of flashes. Ultimately what I'd like to see happen is the menu slide up, only leaving the blue toggle tab visible which happens to be 25px. Then click that same tab and have the menu return. Here is the url again file:///Users/gregtaylor/Desktop/CAITMIZZI.COM/test.html